# Simple SED statement to truncate everything after first instance of underscore AFTER @ sign

Tags: sed

**Input:**

```
ab_cd@yahoo.co.uk_DN_135.PNG
ef_gh@gmail.com_ST_19_1_9.jpg
```

**Required Output:**

```
ab_cd@yahoo.co.uk
ef_gh@gmail.com
```

I'm looking for a SED statement to do the above.

Essentially I would like everything from and including the first underscore character AFTER the @ sign to be removed from the output.

I'm sorry I only have basic knowledge of programming. I'm on a Windows machine [I've found a SED editor] from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) 
and use it modify simple strings in a batch file from the Windows shell.

Many thanks

Comment: To be clear - sed CANNOT use strings in its search or replacement expressions. sed works on regular expressions and has several characters/substrings that it requires you not to use in those regexps nor replacement text so the set of chars an expression in sed requires you to not use or escape is extensive. sed simply has no ability to operate on strings - if you need to use strings, you need to use awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be a way:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*@[^_]*).*/\1/' file
ab_cd@yahoo.co.uk
ef_gh@gmail.com
```

It catches all the text before `@`, after it and up to `_`. Then, it prints it back, getting rid of everything coming from `_`.

#### Explanation

Matching group: given a `sed 's/something/back/'` command, whatever you "catch" in the  part, can be enclosed in parenthesis so that you can refer back to it with `\1` (first match), `\2` (2nd match), and up to `\9`.

```
$ cat file
hello33bye
hello44goodbye
hello55yeah

$ sed 's/hello([0-9]*).*/\1/g' a
33
44
55
```

So `(.*@[^_]*).*` means: catch a block of text followed by @ and followed with any character appart from `_`. Then, catch the rest of the text.
Finally, print the catched block back.

---

To be sure we are not matching a `_` within the domain:

```
sed -r 's/(.*@[^\.]*[^_]*).*/\1/' file
              ^^^^^^
              catch a dot before catching an underscore
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
ab_cd@yahoo.co.uk_DN_135.PNG
ef_gh@gmail.com_ST_19_1_9.jpg
aaa@gma_il.com_ST_BB
aaa@gma_il.com
$ sed -r 's/(.*@[^\.]*[^_]*).*/\1/' a
ab_cd@yahoo.co.uk
ef_gh@gmail.com
aaa@gma_il.com
aaa@gma_il.com
```

Comment: Thank you - both methods worked. I'm just learning SED - can you translate the above line into English - hence what is the significance of the \1 and how does this differ from the approach that kent used and I will then look up some SED tutorials and work back to make sure I understand it !!!!

Comment: This fail if there is `_` in domain name, like this `test@home_net.com_FJ_ef.jpg`. This is a legal character.

Answer (score 5):

give this a try:

```
sed 's/_[^@]*$//' file
```

it worked here with your input:

```
kent$  cat f
ab_cd@yahoo.co.uk_DN_135.PNG
ef_gh@gmail.com_ST_19_1_9.jpg

kent$  sed 's/_[^@]*$//' f
ab_cd@yahoo.co.uk
ef_gh@gmail.com
```

Comment: Very clever, get a big +1 from me!

Comment: Works perfectly thank you. I'm just learning SED - can you translate the above line into English - hence what is the significance of the [] and the $ and how does this differ from the approach that fedorqui used and I will then look up some SED tutorials and work back to make sure I understand it !!!!

Comment: This fail if there is `_` in domain name, like this `test@home_net.com_FJ_ef.jpg`.  This is a legal character.

Comment: @Jotne you are right. but OP doesn't want to extract "domain", and he didn't mention there is "domain name" in the text. read the question title please.

Comment: It is interesting that we can provide an answer that concisely answers the question asked, works perfectly for all provided sample input, and yet probably is not what the OP actually wanted. +1 for answering the question with the briefest, clearest possible script!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` version.  (`awk` is normal more easy to understand than `sed`)

```
cat file
ab_cd@yahoo.co.uk_DN_135.PNG
ef_gh@gmail.com_ST_19_1_9.jpg
test@home_net.com_BO_22.jpg
```

```
awk -F\. '{NF--;split($NF,a,"_");$NF=a[1]}1' OFS=\. file
ab_cd@yahoo.co.uk
ef_gh@gmail.com
test@home_net.com
```

It removes the last field when split by `.`, then divide last field by `_` and replace it by first part of it.